# Procedure to convert MATLAB code to scilab and execute it

Tags: windows, matlab, scilab

My question is how to convert a MATLAB file to scilab file..and also the process to execute it on Windows.I am presently using scilab 5.5.2 version on Windows 7.i found a converter in the title bar in the applications tab.MATLAB to scilab converter.but did not know how to use it.can anyone please help...

Comment: Added appropriate tags

Comment: If there is a menu function, there must be a documentation for it... Have you found it?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a look at the mfile2sci and translatepaths functions help pages